# Spring Cloud Data Flow behind a web proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I want to put SCDF's dashboard behind zuul (or just assume any proxy, really), but when I do that, Spring Cloud Data Flow will redirect to what it thinks it's actual host is.

Example:
Zuul is http://zuul/.  It's configured to route any /dashboard requests to http://scdf/host

In a browser, I go to http://zuul/dashboard.

As soon as the request routes through zuul, and then hits SCDF, SCDF will redirect to http://scdfhost/dashboard, which won't work in a locked down environment. (scdfhost will not be visible through the outside)

I've looked for any properties that would work here, but I can't figure it out.

Anyone tried this? Or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question! The issue is the redirect `302` from `http://localhost:9393/dashboard` to the absolute URI of the dashboard (http://localhost:9393/dashboard/index.html). If you are running *Spring Cloud Data Flow Server* behind a proxy server, such as [Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul), you will have to specify the property
`server.use-forward-headers` and set it to `true`. That way Spring Boot is aware of the HTTP forward headers from the proxy. See also the [Spring Boot reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-behind-a-proxy-server) ("Running Behind a Front-end Proxy Server").

You can find a basic example at:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/dataflow-zuul

In order to clarify the reference documentation, I have created a follow-up issue:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2929

Comment: Thank you so much Gunnar.  I knew this would be more of a Spring Boot question that SCDF question.

Comment: Gunnar, holy cow you made that simple just... yesterday ! That's dedication, wow.

Comment: <humbled>THX</humbled>